# jboss hang on drop table command

Tags: hibernate, jboss

I have class in which when I call drop command on table, JBoss hangs up:

```
public void cleanUp()
    {
System.out.println("******************* Inside Cleanup *************************");
        try
        {
            factory=HibernateUtils.getFactory();
            session=factory.openSession();
            i = 1;

            if(session.createQuery("from AccountPOJO").list().isEmpty())
            {
                System.out.println("First time Accessing NO DATA FOUND....");
                employeeAutoPopulateEntries();
                session.close();
            }
            else 
            {

                System.out.println("Dropping transaction table ");
                transaction=session.beginTransaction();
                Query query = session.createSQLQuery("drop table  Transaction ");
                query.executeUpdate();
                transaction.commit();

                transaction=session.beginTransaction();
                System.out.println("Dropping accounts table ");
                 query = session.createSQLQuery("drop table    Account ");
                query.executeUpdate();
                transaction.commit();

                transaction=session.beginTransaction();
                System.out.println("Dropping Employee table ");
                query = session.createSQLQuery("drop table   Employee ");
                query.executeUpdate();
                transaction.commit();

                session.close();
                HibernateUtils.domanulaConfigration();
                employeeAutoPopulateEntries();
            }
        }
        catch(SQLGrammarException  | IOException | ParseException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("No table Account and Employeee Existed..."); 
        }
    }
```

After dropping the Account table it hangs up, no further action is performed by JBoss, and no exception is given.
What is the problem with drop, alter, or delete command in JBoss?

Thanks.

Comment: It could just be taking some time to drop the `Employee` table?

Comment: i think no, because i waited for 2 to 3 min. then also it did not give any error, when running a function through maina method it runs Smooth and did not wait to drop table, but when i deployed the war on jboss and called function, it just hangs up at drop table Account